# Physical understanding of $n_j$ in $\epsilon_j=\hbar \omega_j(n_j + \frac 1 2)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

I am trying to understand or have a physical interpretation of what it means when $\epsilon_j$ has different values of $n_j$. I will try to elaborate with the following example.

When we consider a particle in a box, it's energy can be given as : $\epsilon=\frac {p^2}{2m}$

But it can also be given as: $\epsilon_n=\frac{p_n^2}{2m}=\frac{\pi^2\hbar^2}{2m}(\frac{n_x^2}{L_x^2}+ \frac{n_y^2}{L_y^2}+\frac{n_z^2}{L_z^2})$

We can say that for two different $n_1=n_{1x} + n_{1y}+n_{1z}$ and $n_2=n_{2x} + n_{2y}+n_{2z}$ the particle will have two different energy values, which translates to different $\vec p$, which physically can be understood as the particle with the higher energy value moves faster then the one with a lower value. So I consider this as a physical interpretation of what it means to have different quantum number n values for a particle in a box.

I am trying to do the same for an harmonic oscillator (consider this harmonic oschillator as part of a solid made out of $N$ 3D harmonic oscillators). For one, it's energy is of the form

$\epsilon_j=\hbar\omega_j(n_j + \frac 1 2)$.

Imagine having to identical oscillators, with the same frequency value $\omega_j$. Let's suppose that the first one has $n_{1j}> n_{2j}$ has a larger value of the quantum number then the 2nd one (first oschillator is in the first excited state, while the 2nd one is in a ground state, this would be an example of what I mean). Since they have same frequency, that means their oschillation is identical, it takes same amount of time for a full oscillation.

**So my question is, how can you tell them apart, in the same way that one could determine that the particle with the higher quantum number value, is the one that moves faster. For two different $n_j$ values for an oschillator, what is "visibly" different?**

Comment: Not a full answer, just a thought provoking question, so only writing a comment:
What is the classical analogon? Think of a classical harmonic oscillator. What distinguishes two identical HOs with different energies? They also oscillate at the same frequency, so how can you tell them apart?

Comment: classically, would that be that the one with higher energy has a bigger displacement from origin? But since frequency is the same, it would complete a circle in the same time, which maybe it somehow means that the wavelength is shorter?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. And also the momentum of the mass at the lowest position is also greater for the HO with higher energy. That is also true for the quantum harmonic oscillator. So the de Broglie wavelength is shorter as well.

Comment: And how can I via calculations/derivation show that the one with higher quantum number value has shorter wavelength? I don't know how to correlate larger displacement from equilibrium with the time it takes to return to the same position (Period)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Generally in two different states **every** physical observable will behave differently, namely there will be a different probability distribution for the measurement result of every physical observable (such as position and momentum). You can calculate those distributions from the wave functions of the corresponding states.

Comment: You can show that for the harmonic oscillator higher energy means shorter wavelength at the equilibrium position by examining the wave function (either visually or mathematically).

Comment: @imbAF There is a state of the quantum harmonic oscillator (QHO) that gives good intuition about what is going on. It is called "coherent state". Maybe look that up, including the position representation of the wave function.

Comment: I wrote $\epsilon=\frac{hc}{\lambda}$ And since the 2 oschillators have different energies, and the one with higher must have shorter wavelength. I did it! Thank you all for the help

Comment: I expect I'm being dense (not unusual for me) but I don't understand how the idea of wavelength can be applied to a single oscillator, for example by applying the equation $E=\frac{hc}{\lambda}$

Comment: the oscillator oscillates, a wave does the same thing, the difference is that while an oschillator has use of the temporal frequency $\omega$, a wave propagating in a medium\vacuum has use of the spatial frequency $\vec k$, and these are related to each other via the dispersion relation $\omega=ck$. For a massless particle $\epsilon=pc=\frac {h c}{\lambda}$. That's one way, I believe you can find what you are asking